# Assigning F12 Developer Tools to a specific button on my mouse

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, ie-developer-tools

I am a big fan of F12 Developer Tools. My mouse has a special programmable button and I would like to assign the 'F12' shortcut key to this button.

Whenever I press this special mouse button I have the Developer Tools showing/hiding.

**Now the problem**: when I `Start Debugging` inside Visual Studio 2012, my trick doesn't work anymore: nothing happened when I pressed the special button on my mouse, but the F12 key works (showing the developer tools).

The trick with my mouse works only if I start Internet Explorer "the classic way" (from shortcut on my desktop for example).

PS: Windows 8 + Visual Studio 2012 + Internet Explorer 11

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

When you were starting debugging from Visual Studio was it for a ASP.net project with script debugging enabled? If you attach a native debugger to IE the F12 key causes a 'break' [feature](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130667) in native. I doubt that's your problem but it's one of the fun things about the F12 key.